# sort an array of integers from file and return them in another file

Tags: c#

Write a complete program that reads all the integers from a file called ‘file.txt’ and stores them in an array (number of elements is not known). Your program should then remove the duplicated numbers, find and print the sum of all the even numbers in the array as well as the sum of all the odd numbers in the array, decides and prints the which sum is greater.

Your program should at least have the following functions:

1- Function remove_dup which removes duplicated elements from the array.

2- Function Sum_Even_Odd which takes an array (after removing duplications) and 
returns the sum of the even and the sum of the odd numbers in it.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Put some code dude. You are a new user so no negative mark but this community works only for those who post some code with a question.

Comment: i have created the array abd read it from a file and i could sort it into eveb and odd numbers but how to split the numbers by spacing and how to find the duplicated ones

Comment: okay i'll put my code soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is quite broad and this isn't free software-writing forum, I won't post exact answer. But I will give some guidelines, which you may find useful if you are looking for them instead of ready-to-use solution (which isn't welcome here).

If you have file organised in such way that every number is in separate line (one number per line), you could use below to read the file:

```
int[] numbers = File.ReadAllLines("path to your file").Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray();
```

Then, to find max, min and sum, you could use appropriate methods:

```
numbers.Max();
numbers.Min();
numbers.Sum();
```

For ordering you can use:

```
numbers.OrderBy(n => n);
```

Removing duplicates:

```
numbers.Distinct();
```

Also, remeber about exceptions! Those can occur while reading a file and when parsing numbers. You should put those lines of code in appropriate `try..catch` block.

Comment: i don't need the exact solution . all i needed some hints

Comment: why did you use max and min!!

Comment: to sort the lines from max til min??

Comment: @user10797182 Then you got them :) If my answer satisfied your needs, mark it as accepted (green check mark on the left).

Comment: @user10797182 Just investigate how these methods work. Min and max return single number, for sorting you could use `Sort()` method or `OrderBy`, as I suggested.